# What's the difference between chroot and pivot_root?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

During my learning of docker, I hear that the Linux command chroot is not enough to isolate the container and we need a new command called pivot_root, Why? I look up the manual for them but just be confused by more unfamiliar concepts. Especially in the pivot_root man page, it says pivot_root changes the root mount in the mount namespace of the calling process. So what does `root mount` mean? I know that during the boot time of Linux, it mounts the root device to `/` (I'm not sure if I am right), so what's the effect of mounting the root device to another directory using pivot_root? Also I am curious why we need this strange root device. Is it a physical device just like a hard disk?

Comment: The original usage of `pivot_root` is for use when the the kernel is started with an initial ram disk image. The initial ram disk image is mounted as root by the kernel before it starts the init process (whose executable resides in the initial ram disk image). When init on the ram disk is ready for the main system to take over, it "pivots" root to the proper  system root (as specified by the `root=` kernel command-line parameter) and then execs the proper system init program.

Comment: The Unix philosophy of "everything is a file" means there is a single root of the filesystem.  This is set by the kernel at boot and permanently changed by pivot-root.  chroot temporarily hides the old root for a given process and makes a subnode look like the root.  Other processes see the real root.

Answer (score 5):

> During my learning of docker, I hear that the Linux command chroot is not enough to isolate the container and we need a new command called pivot_root, Why?

You can see in the [man page of chroot(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/chroot.2.html) that `chroot` could be easily escaped using `cd ..`. That is because that the root directory of the system, is not the root node of a filesystem, and as a result, `cd ..` that traverses the filesystem, can escape the `chroot`.

> I look up the manual for them but just be confused by more unfamiliar concepts. Especially in the pivot_root man page, it says pivot_root changes the root mount in the mount namespace of the calling process. So what does root mount mean?

To get a rough idea of those concepts, **think of filesystems as a backend for files and folders**. We have different filesystems (ntfs, ext4, etc.) that are implementing a tree of files in a hard disk. There are also special filesystems that are not backed by a hard disk, like tempfs (that is a temporary filesystem using RAM) or devfs (that roughly maps each device to a file). Now, **mounting is the mapping between the directories and files of the system and the filesystems**.

Therefore, `pivot_root`, instead of changing the directory that points to the root (that `chroot` does), changes the mount table, that makes `/` point to another filesystem backend. therefore, `cd ..` will not be defined anymore.

> I know that during the boot time of Linux, it mounts the root device to / (I'm not sure if I am right), so what's the effect of mounting the root device to another directory using pivot_root? Also I am curious why we need this strange root device. Is it a physical device just like a hard disk?

Boot procedure has a few stages that we are not going to describe them all in details here. At one time, the system is running and the directories are backed by a filesystem on the RAM (to do the early stuff). Then, in order to switch from this root directory to another one (which is backed by the hard disk) we can use `pivot_root` (more in [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/126217/when-would-you-use-pivot-root-over-switch-root)) . So, to just cover your question, root device is not a physical device, and is any (virtual or real) filesystem that is mounted to `/`.

Additionally, for the case of containers, we mount a (somehow virtual) filesystem to a directory, and then we `pivot_root` a process into that directory, that makes the root directory of that process and its children set to that point to that filesystem, so that we cannot escape that filesystem (and the directory) which is one step toward a full sandboxed container experience.